# Tensoflow: Calling prediction from a function returns 'RuntimeError: Attempted to use a closed Session'

Tags: python, session, tensorflow, neural-network, with-statement

I have implemented a simple MLP in tensorflow. The structure is a class NeuralNet:

```
class NeuralNet:
    def __init__(self,  **options):
        self.type = options.get('net_type') # MLP, CNN, RNN
        self.n_class = options.get('classes')
        self.alpha = options.get('alpha')
        self.batch_size = options.get('batch_size')
        self.epoch = options.get('epochs')
        self.model = {}
```

It has 3 different function:

- Fit:

  ```
  def fit (self, features, labels):
    if self.type == 'MLP':
      input_size = len(features[0])
      n_nodes_hl1 = input_size//5
      batch_size = 50

      sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

      x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, input_size])
      y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, self.n_class])
      labels = self.labels_to_onehot(labels)

      weights = {'hidden_1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([input_size, n_nodes_hl1])),
                      'output': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1, self.n_class]))}

      biases = {'hidden_1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1])),
                      'output': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.n_class]))}

      def neural_network_model(data, weight, bias):

              l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, weight['hidden_1']), bias['hidden_1'])
              l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)

              output = tf.matmul(l1, weight['output']) + bias['output']

              return output

      sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

      prediction = neural_network_model(x, weights, biases)
      l2 = self.alpha * tf.nn.l2_loss(weights['hidden_1']) + self.alpha * tf.nn.l2_loss(weights['output'])
      cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=prediction)+l2)
      train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.005).minimize(cross_entropy)

      sess=tf.Session()
      sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

      for epoch in range(self.epoch):
              epoch_loss = 0
              i = 0
              while i < len(features):
                  start = i
                  end = i + batch_size
                  batch_x = np.array(features[start:end])
                  batch_y = np.array(labels[start:end])

                  _, c = sess.run([train_step, cross_entropy], feed_dict={x: batch_x,
                                                                y: batch_y})
                  epoch_loss += c
                  i += batch_size



      self.model['session'] = sess
      self.model['y'] = y
      self.model['x'] = x
      self.model['prediction'] = prediction
  ```
- Test (testing accuracy):

  ```
  def test(self, test_features, test_labels):
      with self.model['session']:
          test_labels = np.eye(self.n_class)[[int(int(i)/2) for i in test_labels]]
          correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(self.model['prediction'], 1), tf.argmax(self.model['y'], 1))
          accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))
          accuracy = accuracy.eval({self.model['x']: test_features, self.model['y']: test_labels})
          print('Accuracy:', accuracy)
          return accuracy
  ```
- Predict

  ```
  def predict(self, test_features):
      with self.model['session']:
          pred = self.model['prediction']
          predicted = pred.eval({self.model['x']: test_features})
          return predicted
  ```

When running the predict method, It returns a `RuntimeError:  ('Attempted to use a closed Session.')`

**My question is**:

Why does the `test` method run smoothly, while calling the session the same way in the `predict` method fails?

Would I have to create a tf object and evaluate it? If yes, which object should it be?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't run your code, but I have one hypothesis.
maybe you run the test function after fitting is over.
In the test function, you handle session using context manager('with block').
so, my hypothesis is, your session is automatically closed after session context manager block is finished.

```
def test(self, test_features, test_labels):
    with self.model['session']:
        test_labels = np.eye(self.n_class)[[int(int(i)/2) for i in test_labels]]
        correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(self.model['prediction'], 1), tf.argmax(self.model['y'], 1))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))
        accuracy = accuracy.eval({self.model['x']: test_features, self.model['y']: test_labels})
        print('Accuracy:', accuracy)
        return accuracy
    ## at this point, your session is maybe closed.
```

If my hypothesis is right, you may just pass the sess, and run the graph using sess.run(~) and close manually use sess.close() method.

P.S. Why you first assign interactiveSession() to sess, and run tf.global_variables_initializer()?
I think you just can use tf.global_variables_initializer() once, between the point graph construction is finished and the point start training.

**UPDATED**
In my hypothesis, which function you run at the first time doesn't matter, because both function use 'with' block. any function which run first will close the session at the end of with block.

I suggested to pass the sess, that means,

```
def fit(self, ~):
    # construct graph
    self.sess = tf.Session()

def test(self, ~):
     # codes will be here
     acc_val = self.sess.run([accuracy], feed_dict={~})
     return acc_val

def predict(self, ~):
    # codes will be here
    predicted = self.sess.run([pred], feed_dict={~})
    return predicted
```

I hope this code give you a hunch.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. That gave me a good understanding of the problem, but not an actual solution. Actually, there is no problem when I run either test or predict first, but I can't use any of them a second time. But I can't understand how to use what you mentioned. Could you please update your code?